# AngularJs ngRoute not loading pages on ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know there are already a lot of questions really similar to this one, but I really can't find the solution here.

ng-view is just not loading my pages. Am I missing something too obvious?

App.js:

```
var app = angular.module('crisSite', [
    'ngRoute',
    'PortfolioController',
    'AboutCtrl',
    'ContactCtrl'
  ]);

  var selectedSpecIdGlobal = 0;

  app.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : '/pages/portfolio.html',
        controller : 'PortfolioController'
    })

    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : '/pages/about.html',
        controller : 'AboutCtrl'
    })

    .when('contact', {
        templateUrl : '/pages/contact.html',
        controller : 'ContactCtrl'
    })

    .otherwise('/', {
        templateUrl : '/pages/portfolio.html',
        controller : 'PortfolioController'
    });


  });
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="crisSite">
  <head>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" /> -->

    <link href="stylesheet.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="jqueryfuncs.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">



  </style>
  </head>
  <body class="list-group"  ng-controller="mainController">
    <header>
      <!-- <h1 class="text-center">Cris</h1> -->

    </header>

    <div class="page-content">
        <ul class="main-nav" id="main-nav">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
        </ul>   

        <div class="main">

            <div ng-view></div>

        </div>      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm testing it locally on Chrome and Mozilla.
I read a lot of answers for similar questions, but can't figure out how to make it work.

Is there a better way to "debug" it, instead of trial and error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the correct usage of `.otherwise(...)` ?

I think this is what it should look like

```
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/' /*redirects to portfolio (because you defined it before with "/") */
});
```

**UPDATE**

Just remove those -> `'PortfolioController','AboutCtrl','ContactCtrl'` out of `angular.module([...]);` , you can assign the controller for each route inside of `when(...)` .

Here is a [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yy0zeLc1/1/)

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a modified fiddle of you (please note that I had to use Angular **1.2.1** in the fiddle. But as long as you always use the same versions of angular.js and it's modules everything should be ok.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fafr731a/)**

Comment: Ramis, still doesn't work. I tried some variations here too. Also tried to avoid using otherwise.

Comment: good point! On Chrome, I got this: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=crisSite&p1=Error%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

Comment: I was missing https on angular-route url, but I fixed it

Comment: no no!! still the same problem! The Chrome error is still there. Still didn't figure how to solve it.

Comment: Could you remove `'PortfolioController',
    'AboutCtrl',
    'ContactCtrl'` from your module?

Comment: These controllers were working fine before trying to use ng-route.

Comment: Tried not to call the controllers and avoided the portfolio code, since it is a bit more complex.. got the following error while loading the about page: Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$compile/tpload?p0=%2Fpages%2Fabout.html

Comment: Could you post your entire code into a fiddle? here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: first time using fiddle... not sure I did it right enough: http://jsfiddle.net/dgvolpato/7eyyh8jz/

Comment: thank you very much for the fiddle example! I'll dissect it! Should I mark your answer as correct? I'm also not very experienced on stackoverflow!

Comment: Well, you could give me an upvote until you solve your problem and if my answer (example) really helped you out you can mark my answer as correct. But it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never use a minified lib for testing, it messes with the error reporting. Use the unminified version of angular and you'll get more descriptive reporting.

Second, have you created all four of those controllers, added them, to the crisSite module, and included them in the index.html? It doesn't look like you've placed them in the index.html. Keep a consistent naming convention, either go NameController or NameCtrl.

Third, your contact route is missing the /, and your otherwise should use the syntax Ramis provided.

Lastly, make sure all your references are correct, are those template paths pointing to the correct files?

You will need to post a fiddle or plunker with the full code if you wish us to help further. There are simply too many things that could be going wrong.